# Illegal instruction on trying to perform 1 - (a double number)

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have a number with the name 'a' of data type double, and when this number is less than 0.5 and  say 
b = 1 - a
There is no error.
But when a > 0.5, and I say
b = 1 - a
There is an error at that point in the code (all print statements before this particular line are executed) and the error says 'Illegal Instruction'
What is happening here?

The code is :

```
enter code here
void pwm_duty(double duty)
{
int count;
int on_time;
int off_time;
double on;
double off; 
on = duty * 10; 
off = (1-duty) * 10;
printf("on %f off %f\n",on,off);
on_time = floor(on);    
off_time = floor(off);
printf("Before loop on time is %d off time is %d \n",on_time, off_time);
for(count=0;count<20;count++)
{
    ioctl(fd,1,1);
    delay_ms(on_time);
    ioctl(fd,0,1);
    delay_ms(off_time);
}
printf("Now I am out of the loop lol\n");
}
```

The error is:
Illegal Instruction

Comment: Can you show the code? We need some more context

Comment: And complete error message.

Comment: Were I to guess (which is all I can do since the NSA has it out for this question), your program logic results in an *indeterminate* `double` value being evaluated. I.e., you're evading a var for a floating pointer operation that was never *set* to a valid floating point number. That's all I got.

Comment: Normally this is the result of either corruption or numbers going across word boundaries.  Some code would help because what you are seeing is a side effect caused by something else.

Comment: I have added the code to my questiion. This is to be executed on a FriendlyARM board so the function is a part of a bigger code. The duty cycle is to be entered as a part of the main code and the function pwm_duty is called with that number (which is a float value)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something for sure. I do not know how do you accomplish this task, but the right way to accomplish this substractions (and print the result is) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

   void main()

 {
       double a=0.4;
       double b=0.4;
       double c=0.6;


  b = 1 - a;

  printf("b is %f\n",b);

  b = 1 - c;


  printf("b is %f\n",b);

  return;


 }
```

and the corresponding output of this program is

```
$ ./a.out
b is 0.600000
b is 0.400000
```